# Creating Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

Please help,I am a newer in Android Development. I just want to create animation of images dynamically, to say in other words, for example I want to create 3 images and animation with them, then after some conditions it should be become 4 images , 5 images and so on.
When I am creating 3 images separately with 3 Runnables , then it works fine, but when I am creating this 3 Runnables by dynamic array, then it is just doing nothing. Here is code with 3 separately Runnables

```
private Runnable run1= new Runnable() {   
public void run() {
    if(t1)
    {
        LayoutParams params1=(LayoutParams) l1.getLayoutParams();
        params1.x=x1;
        params1.y=y1;
        l1.setLayoutParams(params1);
        x2=r.nextInt(720-80)+80;
        y2=r.nextInt(400-80)+80;

    TranslateAnimation ta1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, x2-x1, 0, y2-y1 );
    ta1.setDuration(800);
    ta1.setFillAfter(true);
    l1.startAnimation(ta1);
    x1=x2;
    y1=y2;

    handler.postDelayed(run1, 800);

    }
}
```

And the same for Run2 and Run3
It works fine, but the following do nothing

```
for(j=0;j<c;j++)    
{
    run[j]=new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
            if(t[j])

            {

                params[j]=(LayoutParams) images[j].getLayoutParams();
                params[j].x=x1[j];
                params[j].y=y1[j];
                images[j].setLayoutParams(params[j]);

                x2[j]=r.nextInt(720-80)+80;
                y2[j]=r.nextInt(400-80)+80;

                ta[j] = new TranslateAnimation(0, x2[j]-x1[j], 0, y2[j]-y1[j] );
                ta[j].setDuration(200);
                ta[j].setFillAfter(true);
                images[j].startAnimation(ta[j]);
                x1[j]=x2[j];
                y1[j]=y2[j];

                handler.postDelayed(run[j], 200);   
            }
        }

  };
for(j=0;j<c;j++)    
{
    this.runOnUiThread(run[j]);
}
```

How to fix this, I mean how to create animation with dynamic number of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should check whether your t[j] become "true", or it always stays false(I think you forgot to set t[j] on true).
Second there is another good way for creating animation of images dynamically. Instead of using images in common class,  you should present each image as an object of the separate class, which should provide 2 attributes: name of image and own boolean t for deciding whether this object should animate.This class should implement Runnable. Then you can dynamically create array of objects of this class and for each object run animation.I am an objective C developer, so here is the code that you can easily transfer for android.

```
class Single implement Runnable
{
UIImageView* image;
bool t;
//method run{

 //here you should create animation code

}
class common
{
 static int c=3;
 Single[] arrayOfObj=new Single[3];
 //method onCreate
{
//create objects of arrayOfObj with images that you want and then call run method for    each object 
}
}
```